# Determinant Of Matrix (A) - Confusion about wording of the question.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image: Determinant Of Matrix A]

Okay, So I'm a bit confused on what to do for this question. I figured out that Det(B) is just the determinant of matrix A and that matrix B is just the upper-triangular version of Matrix A. But how do you find out det(A)?? I tried many different ways, but for some reason it always yields the wrong answer.

edit: I read the comments and figured out a lot of people don't understand what I'm confused about. I found already Matrix B and det(b). I'm confused on how to find det(a).

[image]

Comment: Welcome at MSE. What do you know about determinants and row operations? There are some very easy reductions in the first column.

Comment: Matrix B is the upper triangular version of matrix A? How is a 3-by-3 all zero matrix "an upper triangular version" of a non-zero 4-by-4 matrix?

Comment: @5xum all the dark rectangles are entries that the user should fill in.

Comment: I edited the question for people to better understand what I'm in need of understanding.

Comment: Each row operation has a specific effect on the determinant. For example, dividing every entry of a row by $17$ divides the determinant by $17$. So if you keep track of the row operations you did, and of the effect of each one, you can compute the relation of the determinant of $A$ to that of the upper triangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you convert $A$ to an upper-triangular matrix $C$. And suppose that $B$ is the bottom-right $3 \times 3$ submatrix of $C$. Then we know that $\det(C) = c_{11}\det(B)$, where $c_{11}$ is the top-left element of $C$. You can find the relationship between $\det(A)$ and $\det(C)$ by keeping track of the operations you used to do the diagonalization. Hence you can find $\det(A)$

Comment: Edited after I read Gerry Myerson's comment and realized my mistake.